# If $A$ is positive definite then any principal submatrix of $A$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

> If $A$ is positive definite then any principal submatrix of $A$ is  positive definite.

### Proof;

[image]

In the proof i dont understand about $j_i$'s.. Can some one interpret the proof in a simpler way(may be the original one is simpler)

if someboy is rewriting the proof it would give me a better understanding.(if possible)

Comment: Looks like the author defined principal submatrix as one with the same indices of columns and rows removed. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $j_i$'s represent the coordinates removed from $A$ to obtain the principal submatrix $B$. So we want to show $y^{\intercal}By > 0$ for all non-zero $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-s}$. The argument shows that any such $y$ can be exported to some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (by choosing the missing coordinates as zero) such that $y^{\intercal}By = x^{\intercal}Ax$. Then the result follows.

Comment: can you please elaborate on it more?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof is saying that since x can be anything, we can let the first part of x be 0s and the rest be any number (z). The final result depends now only on the submatrix and since z can be anything, that means x is an arbitrary vector.